# wcf user authentication

Tags: android, wcf, oauth-2.0

I intent to create an android app, that communicate with a wcf service that do all the business operation and get all the data back to app. I’ve wondering how the best way to do user authentication on this service. I was thinking but didn’t know if possible when the user logging on facebook use that token and information to authenticate also in my wcf service.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Oauth2](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html), this has a pretty complete explanation of what you can do.